# Why is there a space required in between the end of my selector and the ending quote?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, string-concatenation

The comment in the code shows where the space is after the selector. If I remove the space before the closing quote the code breaks and I do not understand why. Can someone please explain? Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("document").ready(function() {    
        buildBookmarks('h3', 'header'); 
    }); 

    function buildBookmarks(strWhichTag, sBookMarkNode) {

        var cAnchorCount = 0;
        var oList = $("<ul id='bookmarksList'>");
```

Below is the space after the closing )

```
        $("div:not([id=header]) " + strWhichTag).each(function() {
            $(this).html("<a name='bookmark" + cAnchorCount + "'></a>" + $(this).html());
            oList.append($("<li><a href='#bookmark" + cAnchorCount++  + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>"));
        });

        $("#" + sBookMarkNode).append(oList);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A space required where, exactly?

Comment: There's no comment in this code.

Comment: "div:not([id=header]) " <--Right here before the closing quotation.

Comment: So you want to know the difference between `"div:not([id=header])h3"` and `"div:not([id=header]) h3"`?

Comment: This depends on the value of `strWhichTag`, which is not disclosed in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `strWhichTag` contains another selector, and it is meant to represent a child of `div:not(...)` when these two selector strings are concatenated.

For example, consider the difference between `div.foo` (div with a class name "foo") and `div .foo` (element with a class name "foo", which is a child of a div)

Answer (score 0):

According to the W3C :

> A descendant selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by **white space**. A descendant selector of the form "A B" matches when an element B is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

If `strWhichTag` is a child of `div:not([id=header])`, there must be a space between the two.